# Tuple and numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples, pickle

I have a list of Dictionaries, each consisting of arrays of strings and floats such as below:

```
Product1 = {
 'Name': 'TLSK',
 'Name2': 'B1940',
 'Tagid': '23456222',
 'Cord': np.array(['09:42:23', '9', '-55:52:32',  '9']),
 'Cord2': np.array([432.34, 222.115]),
 'Ref': 'Siegman corp. 234',
 'Exp': 22.0,
 'CX': np.array([0.00430, 0.00069, 0.00094])
}
```

I sometimes need access to certain elements of Dictionary for further calculations. What I do is I first merge them as follows:

```
Products = (Product1, Product2, Product3, ....)
```

Then I use for loop to store a certain element of each Dictionary as follows

```
Expall=[]
for i in Products:
    exp = i['Exp']
    Expall.append(exp)
```

To me this seems like an inefficient/bad coding and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. I am coming from IDL language and for instance, in IDL you could have access to that info without a `for loop` like this. `Expall = Products[*]['Exp']`

Most of the time, I even have to store the data first and I use `pickle in Python` to do that. Since I am a bit new to python and I heard few good things about pandas and etc, I wanted to see if there is a more efficient/quicker way to handle all this stuff.

Comment: That first object is a dict, not a tuple

Comment: There isn't a super-syntax in Python for looping over a tuple and fetching a value from the element `dict` (other than comprehensions).  You get to write that yourself, or if that offends your sense of "order", hide the action in a function.  `numpy` has fast methods that work with the 'whole' array, but that's just for numeric elements.  (not arrays of dicts).

Comment: Do you really start with a list of dictionaries, name them `product1` etc, and then collect them into a `tuple`?  Or is `Products` that list?  And what's with `pickle`?  Is that way of transfering the list to IDL?

Answer (score 1):

Following could work (**List comprehension**):

if you have separated *Product*i,

```py
[product['Exp'] for product in [Product1, Product2]]
```

if you have *Products*,

```py
[product['Exp'] for product in Products]
```

Comment: Dear my friend. You answered the solution mentioned in the above question by simply changing the syntax. I think the friend who opened this subject is looking for a different way.